# How to execute an awk command by SSH'ing into a remote server using python subprocess Popen call?

Tags: python, awk, ssh, subprocess, popen

I have a log file on a remote server 198.168.111.222 at location /a/logs/file.log where each line is of the form as shown below -

```
1538966781.794|7f5059db5940| 31aaa010| core-0: load 0% perf 1%/0.90 count 3600000
1538966791.798|7f5059db5940| 31aaa010| core-0: load 0% perf 2%/0.90 count 4600000
1538966801.803|7f5059db5940| 31aaa010| core-0: load 0% perf 3%/0.90 count 5600000 
1538966811.809|7f5059db5940| 31aaa010| core-0: load 0% perf 4%/0.90 count 6600000
```

Each line begins with a Unix timestamp. I am interested in getting all such lines that contain the string "perf" and are between the given startTime and endTime parameters. With the above example, it should return -

```
1538966791.798|7f5059db5940| 31aaa010| core-0: load 0% perf 2%/0.90 count 4600000
1538966801.803|7f5059db5940| 31aaa010| core-0: load 0% perf 3%/0.90 count 5600000
```

This is what I have tried -

```
import subprocess
ip = '198.168.111.222'
startTime = '1538966781.794'
endTime = '1538966811.809'
linetype = 'perf'

cmd = '''ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss root@'''+ ip + ''' \'awk '$0 ~ "''' + 
linetype + '''" && $0 > "''' + startTime + '''" && $0 < "''' + endTime + '''"' 
/a/logs/file.log\''''

print(cmd)
loglines = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = loglines.stdout.read().decode('utf-8').strip()
print(output)
```

The output that i am getting is -

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss root@198.168.111.222 'awk '$0 ~ "perf" && $0 > 
"1538966781.794" && $0 < "1538966811.809"' /a/logs/file.log'
awk: fatal: cannot open file `/Users/ira' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

I have tried different combinations of ',' '," " and ' ' ' but no luck. Please guide. Thanks!

Comment: it would simplify your problem a lot if you can either install the `awk` script on the remote machine, or at least `scp` to the `/tmp` dir . Weird that you're getting `cannot open file '/Users/ira'...` instead of `/a/logs/file.log`. I would recommend getting it to work for `awk '{print $0}'  /a/logs/file.log` first. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Thanks for your reply. I tried implementing your suggestion but i get the same error message - 
    ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss root@198.168.111.222 'awk '\$0 ~ "1539285409.374" {print $0}' /a/logs/file.log'
    awk: fatal: cannot open file `/Users/ira' for reading (No such file or directory).
About the script, there are more than 100 servers I have to read from. Hence its a little difficult option. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I see that `\$0` is causing problems. Can you get an even more basic `awk '{print}' /Users/ira...` to work? (Don't do `~ 1539..` until the most basic is working ;-) `ssh -oHostKey..=+ssh-dss...` doesn't make sense, but it could be that the shell is concatenating the output because some variable is not dbl-quoted. Not a python guy, so I'm just looking at this from the `awk/shell` point of view. Do you know for certain that the processing shell is `bash`? Going to look at your code and error msg again. Good luck.

Comment: OR you reduce the quoting headaches by putting as much as you can into a local shell script, mark it as executable with `chmod +x mySshCaller.sh` and then call that from your `python`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Thank you for your time. I tried various options but i got the same error message. My research, although short, got to the conclusion that there is some issue with the interpretation of single and double quotes. Hence, i took the "executing script remotely" route and got the results back using the `communicate()` method. But I still hope someone takes up this code and tries doing it using `awk`. Thanks!